# Blazor WASM CS1503: Cannot convert from IConfigurationSection to Action<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, appsettings

I'm wondering about the following:
In ASP.NET applications I access general configuration sections from `appsettings.json` as follows for example:

```
builder.Services.Configure<FileUploadChecksModel>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("UploadChecks"));
```

Where `FileUploadChecksModel` is a simple model class, which matches the respective section in `appsettings.json`

In a Blazor WASM project I can put `appsettings.json` in `wwwroot` to use it in the same way, however the same line of code as above throws the following error:

> CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<Models.FileUploadChecksModel>'

Turns out the method `builder.Services.Configure()` expects an `IConfiguration` in other ASP.NET applications and `Action<>` in a Blazor WASM project as an argument.

Question is why this is different here and how to best get the the data into my model in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#options-configuration).

One simply needs to add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` nuget package to the Blazor WASM project.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `IConfiguration.Get<>` it is an extension method.

Let say I wanted to load a C# model called ChatSettings.cs

```cs
public class ChatSettings
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
}
```

I update my appsettings to look like this:

```js
{
  ...
  "Chat": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7040/",
    "Scope": "api://xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx/access_as_user"
  }
  ...
}
```

Now create a model for the root of your appsettings.json

```cs
public class LocalConfigurations
{
    public ChatSettings Chat { get; set; }
}
```

In program.cs

```cs
    var config = builder.Configuration.Get<LocalConfigurations>();
```

If you wish to access this info from another service or razor component add this

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => config);
```

In a service just add it to your constructor.

```cs
public class SomeService 
{
    public SomeService(LocalConfigurations config)
    {
        ChatSettings chatConfig = config.Chat;
    }
}
```

In a .razor file use the @inject or [Inject] attribute on the property

```
@inject LocalConfigurations Config

...

@code {
    [Inject]
    private LocalConfigurations Config { get; set; }
}
```

**Use one method of injecting not both**. I prefer the attribute way as I prefer the code behind approach.

You do not have to map everything in your appsettings just the properties you are interested in for "your" code. The deserialization will ignore the other attributes and only map the properties mentioned in your config classes.

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed answer. I was already [able to solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75683170/7745011), but now I'm curious. Is there any advantage using `IConfiguration.Get<>` vs my approach of using `Services.Configure()` and `Configuration.GetSection()`? I got my approach directly from the docs, which is why I am asking.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I got my approach from a senior MS engineer. Whilst my explanation is long winded making it seem daunting it is actually very simple to implement and aligns with other methods like `GetFromJsonAsync<>` etc. I have not gone back since I started using this approach. It's a matter of preference, I guess.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration

Comment: Nah, it is actually pretty much the same amount of coding between the two approaches. Just different ways to get the same data I guess. As far as I can tell the difference is, that in my approach instead of injecting the model directly, a `IOptionsMonitor` is injected, which will read the current value form the json file during runtime when it is needed instead of doing so during startup as in your approach.

Comment: @RolandDeschain you don't have to do the Get<> in program cs you can access IConfiguration from your service or component. Also Injecting as a singleton means the io will only be done once. Not relevant to your case doing this in program.cs is useful for the configuration of httpclient base url's for a client factory etc.